# Are there any *FREE*, open source .NET shopping carts that allow bulk importing?

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce

I have reviewed DashCommerce, nopCommerce and DotShoppingCart for possible use and all of them seem to not allow any way to do bulk product/category/manufacturer/etc imports from existing data (DotShoppingCart seems to allow it only in the paid version).

The company I work for has some 30,000 products that we would need to load, and at least a thousand categories or so.  Obviously this is ridiculous to have to manually type in, and as I've stated before in previous questions the company is insanely cheap and won't pay for software, so I need a free solution.

I don't have the time to roll my own solution by following the ASP.NET MVC Storefront series, or else I would just do that;  My boss seems to think creating an online store is trivially simple (I had slapped together a Classic ASP site a few months back but we recently changed our primary vendor so I can't use most of it; it was pretty much hacked together anyway and I can't really use it without reworking a lot of it for the new supplier) and I don't want to hear him if/when I tell him I need a couple of months; he's already waited 90 days since he has some SEO expert on retainer to start blogging/marketing it and doesn't understand that writing software takes time, it's not something that can be thrown together in a week or even a month.

Is there anything out there that can meet these requirements?  In a pinch I guess I could install DashCommerce or something and interrogate the database schema it creates to force an import myself to give him a quick solution that he seems to want.

Comment: Yeah.  I'm screwed, aren't I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would take about 20 minutes to write a simple app that would connect to the database and insert the rows. All you need is a loop that reads a row, writes a row...